# Calling other class from inner class

Tags: python

Hi guys i am planning to call the other class from other class parameter.The code i have tried

```
class barber:
  def __init__(self, age, money):
    self.age = age
    self.money = money

class Employee:
   def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name

   def displayCount(self):
     print "Total Employee"

emp1 = Employee(barber(2,5))
print emp1.self.age
```

When i tried this code i got a blank page without any errors ..Can you guys point me where am going wrong ??..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
print emp1.name.age
```

It will correctly report that the barber is 2 years old.  Scary.

But that's probably not what you want--the problem is you assigned the barber to be the "name" of the employee.  I guess you can fix that though.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken in believing that the `emp1` instance of class `Employee` contains something called `self`.  It contains something called `name` and that `name` member references an object of type `barber`.

Note that:

- It's a little odd to use the name `name` to refer to an object that isn't a string, isn't a name, and doesn't contain a name.
- You have one class that starts with a capital letter and one that starts with a lower-case letter. It's more common to follow a regular pattern of naming classes.
- While there are times in which you might want to have an `Employee` class that takes a specific type of employee in its constructor and "wraps" that object, it's more common to use `Employee` as a base class and *descend* other, more specific classes from that base class.